how to store/append multiple dates in Bash
How can I store values and concatenate them to one variable? all_dt (final variable) should take this into account that it is possible that output of both variables in A or output from B or both A, and B may not have any date values but
A) start_dt_inc and end_dt variables store two date values:
start_dt_incr=$(psql -q -A -t -c "select cast(coalesce(max(date_key),'1900-01-01')+ interval '1 day' as varchar (10)) from target table;" -d ${database_name})

 end_dt=$(psql -q -A -t -c "select process_dt from process_table;" -d ${database_name})

For this example, assume stored values are:
start_dt_incr='2024-05-02' 
end_dt='2024-05-03'

B) Can I store the output of this sql in variable "start_end_dt_hist" like below (please see attempt#1)?
 SELECT concat(cast(MIN(g.dt)::date as CHAR(10)), '|',cast(MAX(g.dt)::date as CHAR(10)))
FROM generate_series(date '2019-06-25', '2024-01-15', '1 day') g(dt)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM g.dt)
ORDER BY MIN(g.dt)::date;

Result:
2019-06-25|2019-12-31
2020-01-01|2020-12-31
2021-01-01|2021-12-31
2022-01-01|2022-12-31
2023-01-01|2023-12-31
2024-01-01|2024-01-15 

Attemtp#1: store historical dates in variable:
start_end_dt_hist=$(psql -q -A -t -c "SELECT concat(cast(MIN(g.dt)::date as CHAR(10)), '|',cast(MAX(g.dt)::date as CHAR(10))) FROM generate_series(date '2019-06-25', '2024-01-15', '1 day') g(dt) GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM g.dt) ORDER BY MIN(g.dt)::date;" -d ${database_name})

C) How can I concatenate values from A, and B (start_dt_incr, end_dt and start_end_dt_hist) as following, assuming variable to hold all of this will be called "all_dt".
all_dt=
2024-05-02|2024-05-03 
2019-06-25|2019-12-31
2020-01-01|2020-12-31
2021-01-01|2021-12-31
2022-01-01|2022-12-31
2023-01-01|2023-12-31
2024-01-01|2024-01-15


pass your script to https://www.shellcheck.net/ , there's a lot of things to fix

Thank you so much for sharing shellcheck, I've updated the code with fixes where required.

The proper process is to edit your original question so that it can be reopened. Now that you have skirted that, perhaps it's best to delete the original (though keep in mind that repeatedly deleting your questions can also carry a penalty)

I've deleted the original post. thank you for sharing about penalty. Does someone have any suggestion on looping?

If anyone needs any clarifications for responding to my question, please let me know. At this point I am still waiting unless I missed something unintentionally, please let me know.

I don't see any part of the code that counts the number of days; maybe just processing year by year, without caring about the total number of days, would be easier.

I've simplified my question to appending values and using them in a loop within Bash script.

I saw the solution but its now disappeared. I've further simplified my questions and hoping this will help with responses. Thank you so much for your help!

You seem to risk getting this question closed by cramming way too many unrelated questions into a single post. We want one question per question, please. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Thank you for your input. Sorry for adding multiple questions to one post. I've removed the loop question and kept it to how to save multiple rows to single variable and how to concatenate two variable outputs (as these are logically related). I hope this will be helpful in answering the question.

poo=$(printf '%s\n' foo bar baz) already creates a multi-line variable; but you have to use echo "$poo" with double quotes around the value (not echo $poo) to see that this is the case. See also When to wrap quotes around a shell variable

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else

Not sure what exactly do you want.
You can check the following examples, may be they help you to clarify your needs:
1)
  start_dt_incr='2024-05-02' 
  end_dt='2024-05-03'
  start_end_dt_his="$start_dt_incr $end_dt"




  start_end_dt_his="$(psql -q -A -t -c "select cast(coalesce(max(date_key),'1900-01-01')+ interval '1 day' as varchar (10)) from target table;" -d ${database_name}) $(psql -q -A -t -c "select process_dt from process_table;" -d ${database_name})"




start_end_dt_his="start_end_dt_his
$start_dt_incr $end_dt"


Note that array=( $(subcommand) ) is an antipattern -- BashPitfalls #50 goes into more detail. For items where there's one item per line (where bash 4.0 or later is in use), readaray -t array < <(subcommand) is preferred; for compatibility with bash 3.2, one instead ends up with a BashFAQ #1 loop appending (array=(); while IFS= read -r item; do array+=( "$item" ); done < <(subcommand))

But I do not use arrays

Indeed -- I saw $($(...)) and read it as ($(...)). The former doesn't make sense, though: Why would you be treating the output of one copy of psql as a new command, and substituting the output of that command into your final variable?

it was just a typo, fixed it

@Saboteur you recommend encapsulating whole sql statement in double quotes as oppose to what I had for instance start_end_dt_his="$(psql..."  instead of start_end_dt_his=$(psql...

@zaino22, for a simple assignment it's the same either way, but in other contexts the double quotes are more correct so some people argue in favor of using them even in assignments where they aren't necessary in order to be in good habits.

Thank you so much Charles for the explanation, I'll add double quotes.
